# Mixing Assembly language and C programs

Tags: c, assembly

I am using a bootloader program which is in Assembly and I am calling a C function frequently to SEND and RECEIVE a Character at a time. The controller I am using seems to have just 3 general purpose registers which it uses frequently. Apart from that I am storing some bytes in fixed RAM locations.

SO, my question is:
Will C function overwrite these RAM location, which were defined in Assembly?

I am doing PUSH and PULL of the concerned registers before going and after coming from these C functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you are concerned about the RAM locations used in your assembly module overlapping with some variable declared in a C module.  You can examine the list file output by your linker to determine if this is the case.  The linker list file will show all of the RAM addresses used by your C modules which you can compare to the fixed RAM locations used in the assembly module.

Note that if your linker does not produce a list file automatically, you will have to read through your linker's documentation to find the right command line option to do so.

Comment: To expand on this, you may be able to use your linker to define named memory locations for your special areas in RAM. Doing that would also reserve the areas, protecting them from other symbols being placed there.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you are keeping the previous values on the stack when doing the c calls you should be fine. Just make sure that you are pushing onto stack before the call and popping off the stack after returning.

Comment: I would add to that to make sure that the RAM locations are as far from the stack as possible if space is limited.

Comment: It's more complicated than that. It depends on the calling convention.

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on the C calling convention that the C code was compiled in. Calling convention is how the caller and callee will communicate with regards to passing data into the function and returning values afterwards. This includes who wil do stuff like back up registers onto the stack before/after calling, will it be necessary to prep the registers before calling the C function, can you guarantee that the registers will return the way they were, etc.

You'll need to find out how the C code was compiled (with what Calling Convention setting). Note that this is also architecture specific. A summary of the different calling conventions and a description of what each entails can be found at Wikipedia here:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calling_convention

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions

On x86, cdecl and stdcall are the most popular conventions. cdecl means your ASM code should do the cleanup, while stdcall says the function being called is responsible for it. If you have the source code for the C function, I would suggest passing the necessary flags to the compiler to make it a "Callee cleanup" convention (usually stdcall, but safecall and fastcall are also options) which means you can safely call the C function without worrying about register corruption.

Comment: I'm not sure the question is about calling convention.  Doesn't the sentence "Apart from that I am storing some bytes in fixed RAM locations"  imply that the bytes stored in fixed RAM locations have nothing to do with the assembler code calling C code?